# Need to show min and max values in MSChart for line graph

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am using MSChart to show blood pressure values sistolic and diastolic, in line chart in a web application using asp.net. The user is allowed to choose a date range before the graph is shown, and we are required to show date in the X axis and the sistolic and diastolic values in the Y axis (two line chart in the same chart area). If the user had entered more than one value for a single day (for sistolic and diastolic), I am required to show the max and min values for sistolic and diastolic.

Is it possible to show that in MSChart, I did a lot of research and went through the samples from Microsoft but could not get any breakthrough, I am at my wits end, any help would be greatly appreciated. By the way is it possible to do that with telerik or by using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` dll.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What is the difficulty that you are facing ? Adding two lines or series to the same chart area is no problem. See the Databinding options (Points.DatabindXY) in the samples from Microsoft. If you want to show the min/max as well, then you should select the right chart type like Stock charts instead of a Line chart.